# Maven JRE error in ubuntu:Eclipse is running in JRE but a jdk is required

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Can anybody help in Eclipse maven error in ubuntu.I found the soln in windows but in ubuntu(linux) i m unable to remove the Eclipse maven error."
Eclipse is running in JRE but a jdk is required".
I have JDK6 installed in ubuntu.

```
$java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)

$ which java
/home/ali/Jdk6/bin/java
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

That may be the your **default** Java installation, but it doesn't mean that's your **only** Java installation.  Assuming you haven't installed any by hand, you should look in Synaptic to see if you have sun-java6-jre installed in addition to sun-java6-sdk (note that sun-java6-jre installs in a subdirectory of where sun-java6-sdk installs.  You may also have OpenJDK installed, et al.

Next, be aware that Eclipse does NOT use $JAVA_HOME to find a JDK to run under.  The VM to use is defined in the eclipse.ini config file, and if one isn't defined there, it looks for a JRE installed under its own directory.

See [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: m2eclipse: Eclipse is running in a JRE, but a JDK is required

G:\study\eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-win32\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javaw.exe"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found a lot of fixes for Windows but not for Ubuntu.

This seems to be working for me in Ubuntu 12.04, with Eclipse Juno:

I followed the instructions here to install Sun Java JDK 6:
http://www.devsniper.com/ubuntu-12-04-install-sun-jdk-6-7/

(if you already have Sun Java JDK installed, then maybe just try the parts labelled "Choose default java" and "Verify the symlinks".)

Then I added the following to my eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java
```

Note that it seems you have to put the new line in, and it must go in the right place in the file, after --laucher.defaultAction but before -vmargs. So my full eclipse.ini now reads:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
-Dandroid.sdk.path=/home/gguser/android-sdk-linux
openFile
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```